# Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received:

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Hello guys i am receiving this error while trying to filter out data when typing on search box.
Here is the search

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchBox" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

I have a ng-repeat where i get the data and cycle through and i have this as the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-if="messages.data">
            <div class="history_box col-lg-12"
                 ng-repeat="x in messages.data | filter:searchBox"
                 ng-click="getSingleHistory(x)">
                    <div class="padding-top row org-info padd0">
                        <p class="org-desc">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-paper-outline"></i>
                        <span>{{x.org_name}}</a></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row org-bottom">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <span><i class="icon ion-ios-location"></i>&nbsp;<b>{{x.org_address}}</b></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <span>
                            <!-- <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i> -->
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar"></i>&nbsp;<b>{{x.ser_date}}</b>
                            </span>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <span>
                            <i class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right"></i>&nbsp;
                            <b ng-switch on="x.sers_id">
                                <!-- <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline"></i>&nbsp; -->
                                <b ng-switch-when="1" class="positive">Accepted</b>
                                <b ng-switch-when="2" class="assertive">Rejected</b>
                                <b ng-switch-when="3" class="balanced">Pending</b>
                            </b> 
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is the data i am getting from request:

```
 data: Object
    0: {ser_id: "108", sers_id: "1", ser_hr: "12", ser_date: "", org_name: "Neymar Football Foundations", …}
    1: {ser_id: "109", sers_id: "1", ser_hr: "5", ser_date: "", org_name: "Xing Fao Foundations", …}
    3: {ser_id: "114", sers_id: "3", ser_hr: "5", ser_date: "", org_name: "Sumidra Foundations", …}
```

This gives me an angular error on expected array. But this is json array right?

here is the controller

```
      var req = $http.get('http://eservicetracker.com/api/services/getServiceList.php?id='+$sessionStorage.user_id);
      req.success(function(data,status,header,config){
          $scope.messages = data;
          console.log("service history data");
          console.log(data);
          //$ionicLoading.hide();
      })
```

Can you guide me on what i am doing wrong ? Thank You.

Comment: Check out this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray

Comment: "But this is json array right?" - wrong. "JSON" is a string format to serialize javascript objects. It has different formats for Objects and Arrays. What you are getting is an Object which is not an instance of Array. To make it array you need to send it like array `[{"ser_id": 1}...]` not like object `{"0": {"ser_id": 1} ...}`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko , thank you for the heads up. I used toArrayFilter and injected the module and used it before the search->x in messages.data | toArray:false |filter:searchBox , now it works fine.